# Is it possible to integrate existing partitions with filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, partition

```
# parted /dev/sda print
Model: ATA WDC WD7500BPVT-2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system Flags
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   primary  ext4        boot
 2      211MB   21.7GB  21.5GB  primary  ext4
 3      21.7GB  34.6GB  12.9GB  primary  ext4
 4      34.6GB  750GB   716GB   primary  ext4

# mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
# mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/var
# mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/home
# df /dev/sda?
Filesystem  ... Use% ...
/dev/sda1       36%
/dev/sda2       91%
/dev/sda3       94%
/dev/sda4       11%
```

BIOS-MBR. Laptop. NEC's LL750/E. It used to have Windows 7 before; erased when I installed new OS. Arch GNU/Linux user. Would like to do with Arch GNU/Linux live usb, because I've already prepared. Any more information to provide?

## Reason why to do so

- At first I decided to do this partition, seeing random articles.
- Was a failure when I wanted to install more and more.
- Then I got adviced that single partition would be enough for many people.
- But should I separate /boot and / yet?

## Is this procedure correct?

1. Erase partition number 3 and 4.
2. Grow partition 2.
3. So does filesystem for partition 2.
4. Remake fstab.

## Others to ask, I think

- Is what I do think appropriate for my object?

## P.S.

- Just got suggested to do these: 1. make a new user. 2. Move everything to /home.
- Also adviced that GParted is safer.
- But I found [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-jp/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/ext4grow); doing `e2fsck -f /dev/sda4; resize2fs /dev/sda4 566G` to make 100G of free space to make it new partition and copy content of / and /var into there, because I was adviced to do so. ... But could have I done `-M`, as man page says so.
- OBTW the procedure is: 1. make /home as small as possible, 2. make 100G of new partition at last, 3. format it, 4. take a backup of /var and /home, 5. remove /var and /home, 6. expand /, 7. copy backups of /var and /home into /, 8. remove last partition, and 9. expand /.
- Now doing `resize2fs -M /dev/sda4`. Oh, should have I pasted size of each partition, in sector-unit.
- Done: `The filesyste on /dev/sda4 is now 18722376 (4k) blocks long.` But WTF that resizing its partition into exact size, I can't mount it yet?

And now (undocumented: unchanged):

```
# parted /dev/sda unit s print free
...
No. Start End Size ... File system
    63s 2047s 1985s     Free space
1 2048s 411647s 409600s ext4
2 411648s 42354687s 41943040s ext4
3 42354688s 67520511s 25165824s ext4
4 67520512s 86242887s 18722376s ext4
    86242888s 1465149167s 1378906280s    Free space
```

Comment: why did you delete so much useful info from the `df` output?   %used is useful, but the mount point is even more so.

Comment: @cas See above command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these instructions below are prefaced with:

## Take your time and be careful & methodical.  You don't want to accidentally wipe your current filesystems.

There's two ways of doing this, depending on whether or not you have, or can afford to buy a 2.5" drive and an external USB dock for it (don't get a self-contained portable drive), **and** if you're comfortable opening up your laptop and swapping the drive (or have a friend who can do the hardware stuff for you).

A 1TB SATA 2.5" SSD can be bought for as little as $125 AUD these days.  In USD, that's less than $90.   If your laptop supports NVME SSDs, they're about the same price and definitely worth getting (over 3 Gbps for NVME vs ~550 Mbps for SATA).  Also, you won't need an external drive dock to do the transfer if you use an NVME drive.

A second drive is, IMO, mandatory because if you're not moving everything to a new drive, you're going to need to do a full backup anyway before you do anything else.   Resizing and moving partitions comes with a considerable risk of losing everything on the drive due to human error, power/battery failure, cosmic rays, marauding drop-bears, or whatever.   Don't even think about doing this without a backup.

If you're moving everything to a new drive, the old drive can be your backup.

I've done stuff like this literally dozens, if not hundreds, of times. The following is my general procedure.  Each system can have its own oddities and quirks, so be ready to adapt slightly as required.

These are not steps to blindly follow without understanding them.

Read ALL of it repeatedly until you understand the purpose behind each step.  Then write down your own version of the plan, as adapted for your system.  Double and then Triple check your plan to make sure you haven't forgotten anything or made a mistake.

#### With a new drive:

- power down and plug in the external drive. or install it if it's an NVME drive.
- boot your live CD and get a root shell.   or use `gparted` for GUI partitioning and formatting.
- The new drive will probably be `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/nvme0n1`. or maybe something entirely different.  run `lsblk | grep disk` to find out.
- partition and format it as you like.  Easiest would be to have a small partition (<= 4GB for swap) and one big partition (for / and everything under it).

If you plan to hibernate/suspend the machine, allocate twice your RAM size to the swap partition.

If you ever intend to put this drive in a machine with UEFI bios, it would be worthwhile having a small (512MB or so) EFI partition to mount as `/boot/EFI`.

The following will all need to be done from a root shell.

- mount the old /, /boot, /var, and /home under /mnt as in your question.
- mount the new / as /target
- run `rsync -av --progress --human --human /mnt /target/`
- run `for i in proc dev sys ; do mount -o bind /$i /target/$i ; done` (this is required so that grub has what it needs inside the chroot)
- `chroot /target`
- edit `/etc/fstab` so that `/` is mounted from your NEW / partition, and all
  other filesystems are deleted or commented out.  Also add or update the entry for your swap partition.
- `grub-install /dev/sdX`  (where sdX is the device node of your NEW drive)
- `update-grub`
- `exit` to get out of the chroot.
- run `sync` because paranoia isn't a bad thing

You should be able to shutdown and swap the new drive into the system.

The new drive should be a lot faster, being an SSD.  And having some swap space on SSD will also help if you sometimes run low on RAM.

#### Without an extra drive:

This method is going to use all that free space on /home (/dev/sda4).

- boot your live CD and get a root shell.
- mount the old /, /boot, /var, and /home under /mnt as in your question.
- `mkdir /mnt/home/home`
- `mv /mnt/home/* /mnt/home/home/`
- run `ls -ld /mnt/home/home` and check that the perms are `drwxr-xr-x`.  If they're not, run `chmod 755 /mnt/home/home`.
- run `mv /mnt/[^h]* /mnt/home`

that will move every file and subdirectory in /mnt that doesn't begin with `h` (i.e. /mnt/home`) to` /mnt/home`.  If you have other dirs in /mnt that begin with` h`(unlikely) you'll have to`mv` them too.

OK, everything that was on /, /var, and /boot should now be one the new / partition (/dev/sda4, used to be just /home), and /home will now be a subdirectory of / rather than a separate partition.

- unmount everything under /mnt.  run `sync` to flush all buffers to disk.
- run `gparted` and delete sda1, sda2, and sda3.

  - Make a small swap partition as /dev/sda1.  or a bigger one if you intend to suspend the laptop.
  - move /dev/sda4 to immediately after the swap partition.   This may (or may not renumber it to /dev/sda2 (i can't remember, exactly. renaming may be optional)
  - resize /dev/sda4 to take up the remainder of the disk

`gparted` will probably do the move and resize as a single operation, once you've confirmed that it's what you want it to do.

- `mount /dev/sda4 /mnt`   (or /dev/sda2 if it got renumbered)
- `for i in proc dev sys ; do mount -o bind /$i /mnt/$i ; done`
- `chroot /mnt`
- edit `/etc/fstab` so that `/` is mounted from what used to be your `/home` partition
- `grub-install /dev/sda`
- `update-grub`
- `exit` to get out of the chroot
- `sync`

and you should be good to reboot into the resized system.

Comment: Doing without an extra drive. Trying `mv /mnt/[^h]* /mnt/home`, space ran out.

Comment: So I did lots of things to enlarge sda4 again. Should not have I done `e2fsck` nor `resize2fs` or whatever? Or should have I resized sda4 much earlier? Attempting to `mv` again produced this: `inter-device move failed: 'boot' to 'home/boot': unable to remove target: Directory not empty`.

Comment: And now sda1 is 2048 to 67520511 (with 67518461 sectors; 32.2G); sda4 is 67520512 to 1465149167 (with 1397628656 sectors; 666.4G). When I mounted sda4, it seemed that about 80G (83498308) had been used.

Comment: In fact I am not using GParted at all; Arch GNU/Linux live environment, which is completely CUI environment, is fine with me.

Comment: ran out of space?  how? you were moving a 21GB and a 13GB partition to a 716GB partition that was mostly empty.

Comment: I very strongly recommend using gparted.   I mostly use the command line, rarely ever use GUI tools, but I make an exception for moving & resizing multiple partitions on a disk.   Getting all the details exactly right on moving and then resizing the partitions and then resizing the filesystems is just too tedious and error-prone. There isn't a CLI program that will do all the calculations and automate the procedure (except possibly the Clonezilla ISO and that's menus, not CLI), so I'm happy to leave it up to a GUI program.

Comment: At first I thought if I could move partition (about 80G) with / to heading of storage; but the room was not enough so I moved it to end of storage (100G) at first; I lost /usr/bin and /usr/lib but I don't think I lost more. Then I thought of remake a new partition to heading of storage to re-install things there.

Comment: IMO your best option now is to backup /home and any config files in /etc, and probably some stuff in /var (e.g. mail spool. and whatever else isn't automatically generated or downloaded from the net), and /usr/local.   Then reinstall from scratch, with one big / partition and a swap partition.

Comment: When space ran out, should have I redone size of partition and filesystem for sda4 at that time before `mv`ing.

Comment: Probably.  I don't know the exact circumstances, so I can only say "you should have done whatever was necessary to ensure there was enough space on sda4 for all the files you were going to mv to it".

Comment: Eventually I lost some datum and I would like to re-install while preserving it. This time, as single root partition.

Comment: Should have I listened to you. OBTW when re-installing, it works as UEFI-GPT.